# Local MQTT broker not reading the .conf file while bridging to cloud MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to connect my local mqtt broker to DIoTY cloud broker. I have taken reference from https://www.losant.com/blog/how-to-configure-mosquitto-bridge-to-losant and done all the configuration file changes as required. My **/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf** looks like

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

I made my separate cloud.conf file in conf.d

```
# Config file for mosquitto

# See mosquitto.conf(5) for more information.

user mosquitto
max_queued_messages 200
message_size_limit 0
allow_zero_length_clientid true
allow_duplicate_messages false

listener 1883
autosave_interval 900
autosave_on_changes false
persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
allow_anonymous true

connection dioty
address mqtt.dioty.co:1883
bridge_attempt_unsubscribe false
remote_username *******
remote_password *******
start_type automatic
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
notifications false
try_private true
bridge_insecure false
cleansession false
topic # in 0
```

Mosquitto logs after starting broker are as follows

```
1608537228: mosquitto version 1.6.12 starting
1608537228: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1608537228: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1608537228: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1608537228: mosquitto version 1.6.12 running
1608539039: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
```

What I think is my local mqtt is not reading .conf file. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65368535/edit) the question to explain how you are starting the broker, the `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and to include the mosquitto logs that are output when it starts so we can see what files it used, what listeners it started and the version numbers

Comment: what are the file permissions on the `cloud.conf` file?

Comment: Also you look to me missing the `remote_clientid` and `bridge_certificate` and using the wrong port (1883, instead of 8883) mentioned in the link at the start of your question

Comment: Also `cloud.conf` file has all read write permissions

Comment: I am not using the secure broker port hence 1883 instead of 8883 and no certificates or `remote_clientid` required

Comment: The doc says you need a clientid (https://docs.losant.com/mqtt/overview/#broker-authentication) and cleansession should be true (https://docs.losant.com/mqtt/overview/#mqtt-version-and-limitations)

Comment: I am not using Losant. I am using DIOTY. I have just taken the reference from that site for setting up the configuration file.

Comment: Thank you @hardillb for the time. I got where I was doing wrong. Apparently DIoTY doesn't require any changes in config file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using Losant configuration to configure DIOTY broket which won't work as both are a different broker.

To save credentials in `mosquitto` config, first, you have to generate the password file using `mosquitto_passwd`

```
mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/passwd USER PASSWORD
```

then add password file location to `mosquitto` config also set `allow_anonymouse=false`

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

That's it now you just need to publish or subscribe using

```
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "test" -m "hello world

mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t test
```